# How to maintain data integrity on rather large external harddisc (with robocopy or other tool)?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, robocopy

I'm having almost 8TB of valuable media (well personally valuable) on an external 8TB HD.

In order to have a backup when it crashes one day, I have second HD to which I regularly copy all the files:

```
robocopy a:\MyFolder b:\MyFolder /MIR
```

Now I am worried, what if some files somehow get corrupted on the first HD. Wont robocopy simply copy these corruptions to the second HD? Will it tell me that file x and y are corrupt and skip them?

Comment: off topic but why not buy a nas or make raid using some old pc? i do this way

Answer (score 0):

Use these Switches **/R:0** and **/W:0** after **/MIR**

So `robocopy a:\MyFolder b:\MyFolder /MIR /R:0 /W:0`

**/R:0** is used to make retries to none. The  **/W:0** is to make no time waiting during copying. These switches will make sure corrupted or files with errors are skipped.

Hope this helps you out in making it less likely for you to copy over corrupted files over your good files.

Helpful source where information is located [Here](http://pureinfotech.com/robocopy-recover-and-skip-files-with-errors-from-bad-hard-drive-in-windows/)